# Is there an easy way to restart a python 3 code once it has ended?

Tags: python, python-3.x, restart, application-restart

I am running a simple program that takes user info, stores it, manipulates it then prints the results.

The program is intended to be run multiple times in a row and it would be nice to be able to do this without having to exit it and restart it again.

Is there a nice simple way to restart the code that doesn't include having to use while x != y loops.

I have scoured google but can only find very long and complex methods, surely there must be a simple command for this?

Comment: Why are you intent on avoiding a simple `while` loop?  Besides, you could always just wrap it in a shell script with a `while` loop ...  If you're looking for a goto, I'm afraid Python doesn't offer that.

Comment: Honestly it's because I have used several already and I am trying to learn new methods since I am new to this. Also I am trying to show diversity throughout the program. If this is the only way to go I will use it but would be nice to know if there are any other ways out there :)

Comment: Try using generators and `map` for your other loops that actually compute things.

Comment: Ok then i'll look into it although I am unfamiliar with map and multiple generators. If someone could post an example as an answer to the question that would be very helpful and I can give them a best answer vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your program:

```
pi = 22./7
print (u"Eureka! \u03C0 == %.2f"%pi)
```

You can invoke it multiple times by making a function:

```
def discover_constant():
    pi = 22./7
    print (u"Eureka! \u03C0 == %.2f"%pi)

# Print PI three times:
discover_constant()
discover_constant()
discover_constant()
```